# Is it possible to edit code with an open visualizer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Out of the box, at least, Visual Studio does not allow editing code during a debugging session when a visualizer is open. The visualizer window is on top and clicking anywhere else in Visual Studio is not allowed.

Is there a setting, extension or other means, that allow editing code while a visualizer is open?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for Edit and Continue.

See the Visual Studio article
[How to: Enable and disable Edit and Continue (C#, VB, C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-and-disable-edit-and-continue?view=vs-2022).

Enable this option is done before debugging, as follows.

> 1. If you're in a debugging session, stop debugging (**Debug > Stop Debugging** or **Shift+F5**).
> 2. In **Tools > Options** > (or **Debug > Options**) > **Debugging** > **General**, select **Enable Edit and Continue and Hot Reload** in the right pane.
>
>    Note
>
>    If IntelliTrace is enabled and you collect both IntelliTrace events
>    and call information, Edit and Continue is disabled. For more
>    information, see
>    [IntelliTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/intellitrace?view=vs-2022).
> 3. For C++ code, make sure **Enable Edit and Continue and Hot Reload** is selected, and set the other options:
>
>    - **Apply changes on continue (Native only)**
>
>      If selected, Visual Studio automatically compiles and applies code changes when you continue debugging from a break state.
>      Otherwise, you can choose to apply changes using **Debug > Apply Code
>      Changes**.
>    - **Warn about stale code (Native only)**
>
>      If selected, gives warnings about stale code.
> 4. Select OK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it does not solve my problem. Edit and comtinue is enabled and it works like a charm. The trouble is that often I would like to visualize the contents of a list, for example, and see that while I make changes to my code. However, I can only interact with the visualizer. The rest of Visual Studio is entirely locked down until I close the visualizer.